# I am using stripe payment java implementation. Stripe refund giving no such charge exist exception exist for the successful payment

Tags: java, stripe-payments, payment, implementation

I have completed the payment through stripe successfully in my java code. But the refund throwing error as "No such charge: ch_1G....."

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("charge",chargeID);
Refund refund = Refund.create(params);
```

Comment: I’m not using Stripe with Java, but to issue refunds I had to also pass in an amount to refund, and it had to be less than or equal to the original transaction amount.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error is encountered when you've mixed up multiple API keys (for example if you have a separate dev or test account), or if you're making charges for connected accounts and you haven't provided the same [account authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication) on a subsequent request.

If you're trying to refund a Charge for a connected account, make sure you [supply the `RequestOptions`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts?lang=java) in your call. Otherwise, double check your API keys match what was used to create the Charge.